# Useless production

Tags: formal-grammars

Kindly consider the following productions. How can I identify a useless production?

```
S->aS|A|C

A->a

B->aa

C->aCb
```

Somebody please guide me.
Zulfi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from $S$ it is impossible to generate a sentential form that contains the nonterminal $B$.

This is easy to see since:

- $S$ only has productions whose body contain $S$ itself, $A$ or $C$.
- $A$ has no nonterminals in the body of its productions.
- $C$ has only $C$ itself in the body of its productions.

This means that the production $B \to aa$ is useless.

Answer (score 1):

*Useless symbols* are those that do not appear in any derivation from the start variable of some terminal string.   If you similarly define *useless productions* to be those productions that are not used in any derivation from the start variable of a terminal string, then observe that the production $B \rightarrow aa$ is useless because $B$ is not reachable from the start variable, and the production $C \rightarrow aCb$ is also useless because it does not derive any terminal string  - once we use this production, the nonterminal symbol $C$ will be contained in every further sentential form, and so we can't obtain a string containing only terminal symbols.